# NodeJS: Function inside function. How to make it synchronous?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await

Say there are two functions A and B both are calling mysql DB via connection.query(...) methods. I am using while loop to iterate through the response in function A.

Again, with the response from function A, calling another DB request in function B and iterate through it's result in another while loop inside.

Getting Asynchronous issues. How to solve this.

```
function A(){
  while(){ //Say, Repeat 10 times
    function B(){
         while(){
            some_result;
         }
    }
  }        
}
```

This is the actual code:

```
app.get('/getmenu', function (req, res) {

  connection.query('SELECT * from zaitoon_menutypes', function (err, rows) {
    var output = [];
    var i=0;
    var j;
    var main= rows[0].mainType;
    var submenu=[];
    var items=[];

    //Iterate through complete menu types
    while( i < rows.length ){

      //Do NOT MENU TYPE switch case
      if (main == rows[i].mainType){


        connection.query("SELECT * from zaitoon_menu WHERE type='type'" , function (err2, rows2, fields2){
        console.log('*************************'+rows2.length);
        items = [];
        j=0;
        while(j < rows2.length){
          items.push(
            {
            "itemCode":rows2[j].code,
            "itemName":rows2[j].name,
            "itemPrice":rows2[j].price
            }
          );
          j++;
        }
        console.log(items);

      }); //End Connection

        //Create Sub-menu
        submenu.push(
          {
            "subType" : rows[i].subType,
            "subName" : rows[i].subName,
            "items" : items
          }
        );

        if ( i ==(rows.length-1) ){
        output.push(
        {
          "mainType":rows[i-1].mainType,
          "mainName":rows[i-1].mainName,
          "submenu": submenu
        }
        );
      }
      }

      //SWITCH NEXT TYPE
      else {
        main = rows[i].mainType;
        output.push(
        {
          "mainType":rows[i-1].mainType,
          "mainName":rows[i-1].mainName,
          "submenu": submenu
        }
        );
        var submenu=[]; 

      }

      i++;
    }

    if (!err){
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(output))
    }
    else
      res.status(500).send('Error ')     
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Nodejs, ***rarely*** should you be doing synchronous calls.  It's bound to hose your system if you do it incorrectly... especially if you have a lot of traffic.  Nodejs is single threaded and and is completely built around being asynchronous in order work correctly.

In your case, you're essentially querying some database records and using those to populate some JSON objects.  At which point when you're all done, you want to send a response which is an array of json objects... right?

I'd highly recommend you look in to using Promises.  A very popular library that can handle this is Bluebird: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html

Please read up on promises so you actually understand what it is they do.  The short answer is that it keeps everything asynchronous, yet allows you to stay away from callback hell while also making your asynchronous code "read" more as if it were synchronous.

Ultimately what you need to do here is promisify your database queries, push the data to its object then resolve.  Once all database calls are resolved, such as using Promise.all(), then you should send back your res.send with the object... and it should be hydrated with everything you need while avoiding your async issues.

Here is an example of what you might do.  **Note that this is untested and I simply did this in notepad++... so likely it will definitely not work if you just copy/paste!**  But it should hopefully point you along the right path....

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var connection = require('mysqllibrary');

app.get('/getmenu', function (req, res) {

  Promise.promisifyAll(connection);

  connection.queryAsync('SELECT * from zaitoon_menutypes')
  .then(function(rows){
        var output = [];
        var i=0;
        var j;
        var main= rows[0].mainType;
        var submenu=[];
        var items=[];
        var promises=[];


        //Iterate through complete menu types
        while( i < rows.length ){

          //Do NOT MENU TYPE switch case
          if (main == rows[i].mainType){

            promises.push(connection.queryAsync("SELECT * from zaitoon_menu WHERE type='type'")
                          .then(function(rows2){
                                console.log('*************************'+rows2.length);
                                items = [];
                                j=0;
                                while(j < rows2.length){
                                  items.push(
                                    {
                                    "itemCode":rows2[j].code,
                                    "itemName":rows2[j].name,
                                    "itemPrice":rows2[j].price
                                    }
                                  );
                                  j++;
                                }
                                console.log(items);
                          }));

            //Create Sub-menu
            submenu.push(
              {
                "subType" : rows[i].subType,
                "subName" : rows[i].subName,
                "items" : items
              }
            );

            if ( i ==(rows.length-1) ){
                output.push(
                {
                  "mainType":rows[i-1].mainType,
                  "mainName":rows[i-1].mainName,
                  "submenu": submenu
                });
            }
          }
          //SWITCH NEXT TYPE
          else {
            main = rows[i].mainType;
            output.push(
            {
              "mainType":rows[i-1].mainType,
              "mainName":rows[i-1].mainName,
              "submenu": submenu
            }
            );
            var submenu=[]; 
          }
          i++;
        }

        return Promise.all(promises).then(function() {
            console.log("Output object has been hydrated");
            return output;
        });

  }).then(function(output){
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(output))
  }).catch(function(err){
      res.status(500).send('Error: ' + err)     
  });   

});
```